# Erro java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Tags: java

boa tarde!
Estava tentando rodar classes de um jar e me deparei com o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Pesquisei e achei esse site : http://www.slf4j.org/

O que é esse erro exatamente?

Answer (score 6):

O erro `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` é uma das exceções *core* do Java, que ocorre em tempo de execução quando uma classe **existente não pôde ser carregada** devido a falta de uma outra classe da qual ela depende ou, por exemplo, quando um bloco de inicialização estático lançou uma exceção.

Ou seja, **esse erro *não* ocorre por falta da classe `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory`, mas por falta de alguma outra classe que ela precisa**.

A biblioteca de logs chamada *Simple Logging Facade for Java* (SLF4J) é apenas uma interface padronizada para acessar logs, mas você ainda precisa incluir uma implementação de logs tal como [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) ou [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), etc.

A forma como se resolve depende de como você usa seu programa:

- Se for um programa simples executando por linha de comando, adicione as dependências necessárias especificando ao classpath do Java com o parâmetro `-cp`.
- Se for uma aplicação web você pode usar logs do servidor de aplicação ou incluir sua biblioteca de log na pasta `WEB-INF/lib`.

Quais jars devem ser incluídos no classpath depende de qual biblioteca é usada em conjunto com o SLF4J e de quais funcionalidades a aplicação usa:

- Para logs simples usando apenas SLF4J, você pode incluir:

  - `slf4j-api-1.x.xx.jar`
  - `slf4j-simple-1.x.xx.jar`
- Para usar o Log4j:

  - `slf4j-api-1.x.xx.jar`
  - `log4j.jar`
  - `slf4j-log4j12-1.x.xx.jar`, o jar de integração entre as duas bibliotecas
- Para usar Logback:

  - `slf4j-api-1.x.xx.jar`
  - `logback-classic-1.0.13.jar`
  - `logback-core-1.0.13.jar`.

Comment: Excelente resposta, serviu até para mim que não sabia como o significado total do erro java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Answer (score 2):

O erro aconteceu porque está faltando a classe [LoggerFactory](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.html)
 no Classpath. Para corrigir basta você adicionar a biblioteca sl4j no Classpath, que  pode encontrar [aqui](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html).

Você pode colocar os arquivos: `slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar` e `slf4j-jdk14-1.7.13.jar` no Classpath.

Comment: Por que `slf4j-jdk14`? Diz em algum lugar que ela usa Java 1.4?

Comment: @utluiz o slf4j-jdk14, foi porque olhei em um tutorial que pedia para colocar esta versão do jdk14.

Comment: O `slf4j-jdk14` é um "plugin" para o framework de logging do Java 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Usando apenas SLF4J, slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar
*Basta clicar botão direito em JRE System... Build Path e adicionar a JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Complementando para quem tiver este mesmo erro no futuro:

Esse erro também pode ocorrer quando você está utilizando uma Biblioteca que usa o slf4j para gerar os log's de erro em tempo de execução.

E este foi o meu caso, estava utilizando a biblioteca kafka-clients e estava recebendo esse erro, adicionei os arquivos: slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar e slf4j-jdk14-1.7.13.jar no Classpath e o erro relacionado ao slf4j parou de ocorrer e o erro que o KAFKA "queria mostrar" apareceu, que no meu caso era firewall entre a maquina que estou rodando o meu producer, com o Servidor de bootstrap.